# Calculate 500m south of coordinate in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, line, coordinates

I have a point layer punkte_test. From that I want to make a line: first point of the line is the point A from the point layer itself. Second point of the line shall be y(B) = y(A) - 500 m . How can I realize that?

That's my idea:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom, concat(ST_X(geom), (ST_Y(geom)-500)))
FROM liechtenstein.punkte_test
```

I use coordinate system UTM, so I want the second point to be 500 m south of A.

Comment: You can maybe use `ST_MakePoint` instead of your "concat" : https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html

Comment: yeah, thats right. ```SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom, st_setsrid(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom), (ST_Y(geom)-500)),25832))
FROM liechtenstein.punkte_test``` gives the line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`st_translate`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html) to move the point

```sql
SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom, st_translate(geom,0,-500))
FROM liechtenstein.punkte_test;
```

Comment: uhh nice thats also a good idea